# Service Variable in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 2 Service for share information between two child Components, both components are communicating well with the service, but i can not set a value to  an variable into the service. Here is the Service's Code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ServiceNotifications {

    newPacient: boolean;

    nuevoPacient$: Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.newPacient);

    constructor() {
      this.newPacient$.asObservable();
    }

    notiNewPacient(status:boolean){
        console.log(status);
        this.newPacient=status;
        this.newPaciet$.next(this.newPacient);
    }
}
```

My problem is that i can not update the variable newPacient with the function notiNewPacient().

Comment: `newPaciet$` isn't defined anywhere but maybe that is a typo. What do you mean you can't update the variable? Also your constructor doesn't do anything

Comment: I want to update "newPacient" with a "true" value every time that a pacient is created. i'm trying to do it with "notiNewPacient()", but i can not get it. the service is working well. the components are connected to the Observable.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the observable.

In your service:

```
constructor() {
  this.newPacient$ = true;
}
```

In your component:

```
constructor(service: serviceNotifications) {
}

get newPacient(): boolean {
  return service.newPacient;
}
```

Then if you want to access newPacient from the Component, you can do so with `this.newPacient`. And from the view, just `newPacient`.